# Need to apply multiple filters to JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

In my project I have a JSON file consisting of guitars and their related data. I am trying to create three filters (brand, category and condition) that immediate load the appropriate data when they are clicked on. My function works perfectly for one filter but I can't figure out how to combine all three.

Initially all the guitars would display and then would be filtered immediately as each filter is applied. How would I go about this? I realize an array of clicked filters is in order but accomplishing this is currently beyond my skill.

example JSON

```
{
    "product_id": "0",
    "category": "electric",
    "condition": "used",
    "justIn": "true",
    "brand": "gibson",
    "year": "1952",
    "code": "456def",
    "img1": "../img/sale/gibson/295-1.jpg",
    "img2": "../img/sale/gibson/295-2.jpg",
    "img3": "../img/sale/gibson/295-3.jpg",
    "img4": "../img/sale/gibson/295-4.jpg",
    "alt": "gibson guitar",
    "title": "Gibson ES-295 1952",
    "price": "6000.00",
    "description": "A beautiful ES-295 with wear you can't fake! The ES-295 was originally produced from 1952 to 1958 and is best known for being the model played by Scotty Moore with Elvis. This particular example plays well with a fantastic feeling neck! The guitar has heavy finish wear with the beautiful greening that you often see on '50s goldtops. Glaser has refretted the guitar and replaced the tailpiece crossbar. The pickguard is missing.",
    "specs": ["Body Wood - Laminated Maple",
              "Neck Wood - Mahogany",
              "Fingerboard Wood - Rosewood",
              "Scale Length - 24.75",
              "Nut Width - 1 11/16",
              "Pickup(s) - Original P-90s",
              "Case - Hard Case"
            ]
  }
```

filter click listener

```
  $("#collapseOne, #collapseTwo, #collapseThree").change("click", e => {
    const checkbox = e.target
    const key = e.target.getAttribute('data-name')
    const id = e.target.id

    loadWithFilter(checkbox, key, id)
  })
```

Data loading function. Based on the JSON I provided, key = brand, value = fender

```
const loadWithFilter = (checkbox, key, value) => {
    $.getJSON("../../json/guitars.json", data => {

      let dataArr = data
      let filterArr = []
      let guitar_data = ""


      for(let i in dataArr) {

        // data
        const image1 = dataArr[i].img1
        const alt = dataArr[i].alt
        const title = dataArr[i].title
        const price = dataArr[i].price

        // filters
        const id = dataArr[i].product_id
        const brand = dataArr[i].brand
        const category = dataArr[i].category
        const condition = dataArr[i].condition

        if (value === brand && $(checkbox).prop("checked") == true) {
          cardElements()
        }
        if ($(checkbox).prop("checked") == false) {
          cardElements()
        }

        function cardElements() {
          guitar_data += `<div class="gallery-card" data-brand="${brand}" data-category="${category}" data-condition="${condition}">`
          guitar_data += `<img class="more-info img-fluid" src="../${image1}" alt="${alt}" data-id="${id}">`
          guitar_data += `<h6>${title}</h6>`
          guitar_data += `<p class="text-center"><strong>$ ${price}</strong></p>`
          guitar_data += '</div>'

          $('#img-gallery').html(guitar_data)
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a filter requires combining various javascript methods(like `filter` and `map`), checkout the following setup that demonstrates a possible setup to filter data.

Try changing the filter input(see demo) from `new` to `used` or clear it to see the results change.

```js
   const resultElem = document.querySelector('#results');
    const filtersElem = document.querySelector('#filters');

    const products = [
        {
            "product_id": "0",
            "category": "electric",
            "condition": "used",
            "justIn": "true",
            "brand": "gibson",
            "year": "1952",
            "code": "456def",
            "alt": "used gibson guitar",
            "title": "Gibson ES-295 1952",
            "price": "6000.00",
            "description": "A beautiful ES-295 with wear you can't fake! The ES-295 was originally produced from 1952 to 1958 and is best known for being the model played by Scotty Moore with Elvis. This particular example plays well with a fantastic feeling neck! The guitar has heavy finish wear with the beautiful greening that you often see on '50s goldtops. Glaser has refretted the guitar and replaced the tailpiece crossbar. The pickguard is missing.",
        },
        {
            "product_id": "0",
            "category": "electric",
            "condition": "new",
            "justIn": "true",
            "brand": "yama",
            "year": "1952",
            "code": "456def",
            "img1": "../img/sale/gibson/295-1.jpg",
            "img2": "../img/sale/gibson/295-2.jpg",
            "img3": "../img/sale/gibson/295-3.jpg",
            "img4": "../img/sale/gibson/295-4.jpg",
            "alt": "yama guitar",
            "title": "new yama ES-295 1952",
            "price": "6000.00",
            "description": "A beautiful ES-295 with wear you can't fake! The ES-295 was originally produced from 1952 to 1958 and is best known for being the model played by Scotty Moore with Elvis. This particular example plays well with a fantastic feeling neck! The guitar has heavy finish wear with the beautiful greening that you often see on '50s goldtops. Glaser has refretted the guitar and replaced the tailpiece crossbar. The pickguard is missing.",
        }
    ];

    const buildResult = ({product_id: id, title, price, brand, category, condition, image1, alt}) => {
        return `<div class="gallery-card" data-brand="${brand}" data-category="${category}" data-condition="${condition}">
         <img class="more-info img-fluid" src="../${image1}" alt="${alt}" data-id="${id}">
         <h6>${title}</h6>
         <p class="text-center"><strong>$ ${price}</strong></p>
         </div>`
    };

    const filterResults = () => {
        const currentFilters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.filter')].map(filterElem => ({
            field: filterElem.dataset.field,
            value: filterElem.value
        }));

        const productsThatMatchCriteria = products.filter(product => {
            return currentFilters.every(filter => {
                return filter.value === '-1' || product[filter.field] === filter.value
            })
        });

        const resultsFormattedAtHtml = productsThatMatchCriteria.map(product => buildResult(product)).join('');

        resultElem.innerHTML = resultsFormattedAtHtml;
    };

    const loadFilters = (fields) => {
        const possibleValues = {};

        products.forEach(product => {
            fields.forEach(fieldName => {
                if (!possibleValues.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
                    possibleValues[fieldName] = new Set();
                }

                possibleValues[fieldName].add(product[fieldName]);
            })
        });

        const selectors = Object.keys(possibleValues).map(fieldName => {
            return `<select class="filter" name="filter[${fieldName}]" data-field="${fieldName}">
                    <option value="-1">All</option>
                    ${[...possibleValues[fieldName]].map(option => `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`).join('')}
                </select>`
        }).join('');

        filtersElem.innerHTML = selectors;

        document.querySelectorAll('.filter').forEach(filter => {
            filter.addEventListener('change', e => {
                filterResults();
            })
        })
    };

    loadFilters(['brand', 'year', 'condition'])
    filterResults();
```

```html
<h1>Filter</h1>
<div>
    <div id="filters">

    </div>
</div>
<h2>Results</h2>
<div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful, but even in your example it's just one filter. I'm having trouble applying multiple filters. Suppose I want to see only Gibson guitars and then from that list I want to see only the used models. I need to apply three filters independent of one another. I could always choose the filters then submit as one but I want to be able to add or remove the filters independently.

Comment: Ah i see, I updated example to include the combination of various filters. @JeffS

Comment: Great! I'll study this to see what I can learn and report back after I incorporate the code. Thanks

Comment: Did the filter setup help? @JeffS

Comment: To be honest the code is a bit beyond my skill and I'm having a difficult time understanding it, let alone incorporating it. I was going to drop it in verbatim, but my filters are not dynamically generated so I don't know how to adjust the code. It obviously works as your snippet shows , getting it to work for me is a challenge. This is my first attempt at something on my own so I expected these roadblocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to iterate over your data array

```js
const data = [{
  "product_id": "0",
  "category": "electric",
  "condition": "used",
  "justIn": "true",
  "brand": "gibson",
  "year": "1952",
  "code": "456def",
  "img1": "../img/sale/gibson/295-1.jpg",
  "img2": "../img/sale/gibson/295-2.jpg",
  "img3": "../img/sale/gibson/295-3.jpg",
  "img4": "../img/sale/gibson/295-4.jpg",
  "alt": "gibson guitar",
  "title": "Gibson ES-295 1952",
  "price": "6000.00",
  "description": "A beautiful ES-295 with wear you can't fake! The ES-295 was originally produced from 1952 to 1958 and is best known for being the model played by Scotty Moore with Elvis. This particular example plays well with a fantastic feeling neck! The guitar has heavy finish wear with the beautiful greening that you often see on '50s goldtops. Glaser has refretted the guitar and replaced the tailpiece crossbar. The pickguard is missing.",
  "specs": ["Body Wood - Laminated Maple",
    "Neck Wood - Mahogany",
    "Fingerboard Wood - Rosewood",
    "Scale Length - 24.75",
    "Nut Width - 1 11/16",
    "Pickup(s) - Original P-90s",
    "Case - Hard Case"
  ]
}]

data.filter(item => {
console.log({
  brand: item.brand,
  condition: item.condition,
  category: item.category
})
})
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt Ahmet but this is not at all what I am trying to do. The filters will be on my web page and I would be loading the entire object if filter parameter matches. This page provides an example of what I'm looking to accomplish https://cartervintage.com/collections/electric-guitars?